# Get table last element depends on parameter using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure like this.

```
<table id="sampleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>col1</td>
           <td>col2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">sub-grouping-1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1 item<td>
            <td>col1 item<td>
        <tr>
        <tr> // last item of the sub group 1
            <td>col1 item<td>
            <td>col1 item<td>
        <tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">sub-grouping-2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> // last item of the sub group 2
            <td>col1 item<td>
            <td>col1 item<td>
        <tr>
     <tbody>
</table>
```

How do I select the last item of each group using jQuery?

**Condition:** The row count is unknown. And what I have is the text of the sub-group to search the last element (sub-grouping-1 in example)

please help I have been stuck on this for a day searching for answer.

Comment: Last item of which group?? please be specific.

Comment: I only have the text of a group. So I want to find the last element of a group depending of what I group text I have.

Comment: You should adopt appropriate html structure to accomplish that. with this structure it is tough one...

Comment: what do you suggest? I can make an ID for each group if it will make it more easier.

Comment: so you need the last td content of each row irrespective of row count am i right?

Comment: not really each row. lets say from `sub-group-1` I only need the last row and first `td` element before the `sub-group-2`

Comment: @user2785929 something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YqggP/2

Comment: @billyonecan can you post it as answer with details so I can give you some credit. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your markup makes this a bit more difficult, but it is still possible. I've added the class `group` to your `sub-group-*` `<td>`'s otherwise there'd be no way to identify the next `sub-grouping-*`:

```
<td colspan="2" class="group">sub-grouping-1</td>
```

Then, given that `text = 'sub-grouping-1`, you can match the corresponding `<td>` using `filter()`, get its closest `<tr>`, then use `nextAll()` to get the next `<tr>` which contains a `<td>` with the class `group`, then get the previous `<tr>`'s last `<td>`:

```
var $last = $('td.group').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == text;  
}).closest('tr').nextAll(':has(td.group):first').prev('tr').find('td:last');
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqggP/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In your OP a lot of `tags` not closed properly, like `td,tr,tbody`. Your `html` markup is not proper to achieve the desired result easily and you should change the `html` markup.

If you still want to use current markup then try this:

HTML

```
<table id="sampleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">sub-grouping-1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>g1 col item 1</td>
            <td>g1 col item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>g1 col item 3</td>
            <td>g1 col2 item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">sub-grouping-2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>g2 col item 1</td>
            <td>g2 col item 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('td[colspan="2"]').each(function(i, v) {
    var next = $(v).parent().next('tr');
    var found = false;
    while (next.length) {
        if (next.find('td[colspan="2"]').length) {
            found = true;
            console.log(next.prev().find('td:last').text());
            break;
        }
        next = next.next('tr');
        i++;
    }
    if (!found) { // next group not found and it's last group
        console.log($(v).parent().next('tr').find('td:last').text());
    }
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/9kLDy/)**